# The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.HTTPStatus error 403.)

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-api, google-drive-api

I am trying to download from google drive file in iOS and getting error in the following

```
GTLServiceDrive* googleDriveService = [[GTLServiceDrive alloc] init];

NSString *urlTest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/%@?alt=media",itemIdentifier[indexPath.row]];
GTMSessionFetcher *fetcherTest = [googleDriveService.fetcherService fetcherWithURLString:urlTest];
[fetcherTest beginFetchWithCompletionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    if (error == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Retrieved file content");
        NSLog(@"File size is : %.2f MB",(float)data.length/1024.0f/1024.0f);
        // Do something with data
    } else {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}];
```

> error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.HTTPStatus
>   error 403.)

Comment: I don't think that is the correct endpoint for the Google Drive api https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/devguide/files

Comment: Please have a look . I have followed your link 
[developers google](https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/devguide/files) 

but still now there is error @DaImTo

Comment: [403 error](https://github.com/google/gdata-objectivec-client/issues/125) typically indicates an authorization problem. You should turn on [HTTP logging](https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client-for-rest/wiki) as mentioned in the GData library's 
introduction documentation, and examine the actual server requests and 
responses.